# How do I connect my website on a external server to my database run off of Xaamp on my local host machine?

Tags: php, html, database, xampp, localhost

I have been building a website for a project using XAMPP. It has a database for users to register which stores their details. I was going to test my website with my friends by physically giving them my laptop however due to coronavirus I can no longer do so. As a result, I have had to upload my website to my university server for people to access the URL, however how can I reconnect this with my database that is on my XAMPP?

The code that I'm not sure how to alter is here and this is in a php file on my uni server (this may not even be the correct code to alter):

```
$db = @mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','databasetable') or die ("Could not connect to server");
```

OR

Is there a way for people to access my XAMPP files on my machine remotely for my friends to test the website and be able to make a log in etc.

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: Why don't you upload your database too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can expose your `localhost` databases by using tools such as http://ngrok.io/.

The command `ngrok tcp 3306` will create a secure tunnel that can be used in your code.